# Segues for passing data from one Table to another

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, segue

I know that we can use segue's to pass data to one tableView to a ViewController.

But I want to use it like from one tableView to another one. Is that possible ?

prepareForSegue method - I tried but couldn't accomplish what I want. (In Swift)

Comment: Yes. You can make a segue connection from a tableview cell to another tableviewcontroller. Or you can make a segue from the tableviewcontroller itself and in didSelectRow do a performSegueWithIdentifier.

Comment: Is the other tableView in the same viewcontroller or in the next viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with next code:

When cell is selected, we gonna push to next view controller:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let data = yourDataArray[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toNextViewController", sender: data)
}
```

And then, we gonna perform our segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toNextViewController") {
        let viewController:NEXTViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NEXTViewController
        viewController.param = sender as! YOURDataObject
    }
}
```

*You have to make a segue connection between your tableViewController and nextViewController ("toNextViewController")

Comment: How can I make it, xCode is saying that sender: data is not 'Anyobject' as program expected

Comment: show me why kind of data do you send. I mean with type ( sender: ? )

Comment: OK , Im a bit newbie so I may did not get the question, but here : I have an array which has dictionaries in it. I want to take those dictionaries to the other table. But I think my sender is ; I have a button under my table , when we click it we will go to next page. Did I give you an answer ??